# Flash Builder - Import SWC and use the buttons?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs6

I can get the SWC into my project and I can see the various buttons it contains but.. I can't seem to get them into my custom class.

I think this might be the answer but I don't know how to format the necessary import statement: [Flash Builder - How to build or include an SWC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333506/flash-builder-how-to-build-or-include-an-swc)

A Pic to demonstrate what I'm saying.
[image]

Comment: have you considered to use the »new« operator and an »addChild« call?

Comment: I don't want to add a button to the swc, I want to get a button from it.

Comment: so since the button is represented by a class in the swc, you can create a new button with new <btnClass>() and add the instance to the display list.

Comment: So you're saying something like var btnAlarms:Button = new btnAlarms(); or am I completely wrong. As that isn't working for me.

Comment: @Mytheral How about: `var buttnAlrams : btnAlarms = new btnAlarms()` ? Your way was creating a new "btnAlarms" object but typing it as a regular old "Button".

Comment: Also, make sure you actually try to compile the code -- if you are relying on those little orange circles with the question mark in them, sometimes they get improperly displayed b/c it thinks there is an error (but it hasn't actually compiled anything). But if you see the red circle instead, that means there was a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer http://forums.adobe.com/thread/864992

It was a simple thing I was over looking the objects just needed a public declaration.